# iterating over values() of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, iteration

I am trying to tokenize each value of dictionary by using for loop but i am getting an error: 'float' object is not iterable. 
My code is:

```py
for doc, answers in answers.items():
    for answer in answers:
        if doc not in tokenized_answers:
            tokenized_answers[doc] = [tokenize(answer, tokenizer)]
        else:
            tokenized_answers[doc].append(tokenize(answer, tokenizer))
```

It's showing error in line: for answer in answers

how can i iterate through the values of dict.values()?

Comment: The error is due to the `answers` being just one value eg `20`. You cannot iterate over this

Comment: If you could show input dictionary it would be helpful. The error message seems to indicate you are trying to iterate over a floating point number in one of your for loops.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to use the name `answers` when it is already bound to a `dict`. Start with `for doc, answer in answers.items():`, drop the inner loop, and go from there.

Comment: my input dictionary is:{28082: ['dielectric resonator antenna', 'slot coupled', 'wideband circular polarizationDESIGN'], 14050: ['Routing', 'Wormhole', 'Intrusion', 'Detection', 'AnomalyMOBILE']}

Comment: The error message implies that the values for at least one of the keys is a float not a sequence/iterable.

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). .. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: thanks @wwii. i understood the problem. There was some NaN values in the dictionary

Comment: Sometimes [Catching the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite helps with diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Note that making `tokenized_answers` a `defaultdict` can simplify your code as you wouldn't need the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

```
for doc, something_other_than_answers in answers.items():
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like one of your answers is not an iterable to avoid the error and to run only on iterables you can make a try except to check for TypeError

```
 for doc, answers_items in answers.items():
    try: 
        for answer in answers_items:
            if doc not in tokenized_answers:
                tokenized_answers[doc] = [tokenize(answer, tokenizer)]
            else:
                tokenized_answers[doc].append(tokenize(answer, tokenizer))
    except TypeError:
        continue
```

That will skip the answers value from the for loop in case it's not an iterable like float.

Comment: Note the double use of `answers` identifier in first line.